# Use python function in a MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql

my workflow is
Extract a CSV file from MySQL database--> open the CSV on Python---> filter the necessary information based on a Python function.

However, I am started to deal with datasets that don't fit on memory. It is also inconvenient to have to import and filter over and over again.

My question is: Is there a way to apply a Python function in a MySQL database? I mean in a way that I only download from MySQL the values that attend my filter based on a Python function.

Note: I use Datagrip.

Answer (score 0):

which python function to apply in MySQL database? Try to apply tests of some libraries! Which one do you like? Tests with a query like "SELECT 1"

```
import time

def query_1k(cur):
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000):
        cur.execute("SELECT 1,2,3,4,5")
        try:
            res = cur.fetchall()
            assert len(res) == 1
            assert res[0] == (1,2,3,4,5)
        except:
            pass
    return time.time() - t

# pip search mysql-connector | grep --color mysql-connector-python
# pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
def mysql_connector_python():
    import mysql.connector
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='localhost')
    print("MySQL Connector/Python:", query_1k(conn.cursor()), "[sec]")


# pip install mysqlclient
# pip3 install mysqlclient
# sudo yum install gcc
def mysqlclient():
    pass
    try:
        import pymysql
        pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import MySQLdb
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', host='localhost')
    print("MySQLdb mysqlclient:", query_1k(conn.cursor()), "[sec]")


def pymysql():
    import pymysql
    conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', host='localhost')
    print("PyMySQL:", query_1k(conn.cursor()), "[sec]")

def msqlchemy():
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    conn = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    print("sqlalchemy mysqlclient:", query_1k(conn), "[sec]")


def pewee():
    # from pewee import *
    user = 'root'
    password = '1234'
    db_name = 'information_schema'
 
    conn = MySQLDatabase(
    db_name, user=user,
    password=password,
    host='localhost'
    )
    print("pewee:", query_1k(conn.cursor()), "[sec]")
    '''
    Warning: (3090, u"Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated.
    SET SESSION sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER";
    
    '''
    
for _ in range(10):  # for PyPy warmup
    print('-------------')
    mysql_connector_python()
    mysqlclient()
    msqlchemy()
    pymysql()
    # pewee()
```